# Multi writes and reads hanging - golang/net pkg

Tags: sockets, go, network-programming

I am trying to learn Golang (and net pkg). I have written a simple client
and server. Client sends two messages in sequence and reads server msg.
Server reads two messages from a client and sends one message - this hand
shake is hanging. Could you suggest what I am missing? Thanks.

When client combine two messages into one and sends it (so the server reads
only once), this does not hang.

```
/* ======= Server start ==============================================*/
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func processClients(cfd net.Conn) {
    clientMsg := make([]byte, 128)
    _, err := cfd.Read(clientMsg) // read client msg
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    clientID := make([]byte, 10)
    _, err = cfd.Read(clientID) // read client id
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    clientMsg = append(clientMsg, clientID...) // TBD: handle len boundaries
    fmt.Println("Server received msg:", string(clientMsg))

    _, err = cfd.Write(clientMsg[0:len(clientMsg)]) // ack client msg
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
}

func initServer() {
    lfd, err := net.Listen("unix", "/tmp/unix.socket")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("net.Listen error", err)
        return
    }

    defer os.Remove("/tmp/unix.socket")

    fmt.Println("Listening on /tmp/unix.socket")
    for {
        fd, err := lfd.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Accept() error", fd)
            break
        }

        go processClients(fd)
    }
}

func main() {
    initServer()
}
/* ======= Server end ===============================================*/ 



/* ======= Client Start ===============================================*/

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup
var clientID int

func sendReq() {
    fd, err := net.Dial("unix", "/tmp/unix.socket")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer fd.Close()

    clientID++
    id := fmt.Sprintf("%v", clientID)
    _, err = fd.Write([]byte(id)) //send client id
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    _, err = fd.Write([]byte("Hello there, I am client")) // send client msg
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    serverMsg := make([]byte, 128)
    _, err = fd.Read(serverMsg) // Read server msg
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(serverMsg))
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    wg.Add(5)
    go sendReq()
    go sendReq()
    go sendReq()
    go sendReq()
    go sendReq()
    wg.Wait()
}
/* ======= Client end ===============================================*/
```

Comment: Your first read  of (up to) 128 bytes reads both id and message. Also, you are writing the client id first but the server expects the message first.

Comment: In other words, it does not matter if you call write once or twice with such short strings. Your kernel will almost certainly combine them into a single write to the "network". You have to delimit your messages in order to take them apart on the server.

Comment: @Peter: Thanks for the quick look. It worked after fixing the order of hand shake and payload lengths. Eventually, I am going to serialize and deserialize (using JSON or some other means).